# Is it possible to null the value of a variable inside a method depending upon the Activity which calls it?

Tags: java, android, methods

I have a method which is called from 5 different activities.Suppose this method displays result by adding 4 different variables 
Eg result=a+b+c+d;

Now if i want to stop the functionality of a certain variable depending on the activity which calls it.

for Eg 
if Activity 1 calls the method then result should be a+b+d(c got null);
or if Activity 4 calls the method then result should be a+c+d(b got null);

Given a,b,c,d contains integer values.
Please help

Comment: There are lots of ways. Make the method take 4 `int` params, 1 `Array` param, etc... But in your specific situation, it's hard to say without seeing your code.

Comment: It would be much easier if you could make [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).
The dirty way might be adding to your activity the variable with it's ID, then check it in method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> First of all integer doesn't have null value its initial value is 0.

Here is an simple example:

```
public void method(int a_val, int b_val, int c_val, int d_val){ 
  if(ACTIVITY == 1){ // condition for activity
     c_val = 0;
  }else if (ACTIVITY == 2){
     ...
  }
  ...
  result = a+ b + c + d;
}
```

Comment: It helped thanks alot